# Экспорт функции go в C - недопустимый символ

Tags: c, golang, dll, x86

Мне нужна помощь, чтобы экспортировать функцию GO dll в C-программу.

Программа на C (автором которой я не являюсь) требует вызова функции с таким именем: _RVExtension@12

Итак, я просто объявляю свою функцию go следующим образом:

```
//export _RVExtension@12
func _RVExtension@12(output *C.char, outputsize C.size_t, input *C.char) {кодкодкодкод.....
```

но когда я пытаюсь скомпилировать его, он возвращает недопустимую ошибку U+0040 '@'.

Знаете ли вы, есть ли обходной путь по этому поводу? Я не знаком с кодом C и не понимаю, почему в названии функции есть @12.

примечание: для 64 битов точка входа проста: RVExtension и работает прекрасно

Comment: Попробуйте просто `_RVExtension`.

Comment: Не могу, требования именно такие, как я написал https://community.bistudio.com/wiki/Extensions

Comment: Вы определитесь, программа у вас все-таки на С или на С++. `_RVExtension@12` - это невалидное имя дли C функции, скорее это mangled имя C++ функции.

Comment: "Не могу" что именно? И что мы должны увидеть по вашей ссылке?

Comment: не могу сделать так, как написал HolyBlackCat. По ссылке которую я привел, есть описание по вызову функции в x86. Она должна выглядеть в моем коде именно так, как описано по ссылке, а go не компилирует, если я сделаю так как написано в статье.

Comment: @VTT - да, С, не с++, извините, ошибся.

Comment: Это в таблице символов оно должно так называться. Компилируйте без собаки и двенадцати. Потом смотрите как называется символ. Если нужно, переименуйте символ вручную. Как это делать в Windows без Cygwin я не знаю.

Comment: А лучше, скомпилируйте с каким-нибудь другим именем, и, используя С, сделайте обёртку для этой функции.

Comment: Есть инструкция как делать обертки?

Comment: @Alexis74, взгляните пожалуйста на этот [пример](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6147097/1816872).

Comment: @Alexis74, а лучше вот на [этот](https://play.golang.org/p/ajb4mD3ZrYG). Комментарии перед `import "C"` будут переданы компилятору Си. При этом `RVExtension` написана на Си и установлены соответствующие атрибуты. Она, RVExtension, в свою очередь вызывает экспортированную функцию Go. Этот пример может быть не точным, но суть сохраняется.